# Group rows of a matrix based on multiple columns

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix `A` that contains in the first column `user_id`, second column `year`, third column `month`, forth column `day`

```
 A=[0 2010 10 19; 
    0 2010 10 19; 
    0 2010 10 18; 
    0 2010 10 18; 
    0 2010 10 17; 
    0 2010 10 17; 
    0 2010 9 20; 
    0 2010 9 19; 
    0 2010 9 19; 
    0 2010 9 19]
```

I want divide this data based on month and day.  How can I do this in MATLAB?

Comment: What do you mean by divide this data? A(:,3) is already your month and A(:,4) is already your date, what do you want to do with them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `splitapply` is a nice function (actually I've never heard of the function until this point) if you have version R2015b.  If you don't have that function, then a call to [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) may be prudent.  Going with the same logic in assigning each unique month and day with a unique ID, you can use `accumarray` to find the row locations that share the same ID, then access the matrix by slicing into it with those row locations and returning a matrix subset per ID in a cell array of elements, much like what `splitapply` does.

Something like this could work:

```
% Assign each unique month/day combination an ID
% From Suever
[~,~,inds] = unique(A(:,[3 4]), 'rows');

% Divide up the rows based upon this ID
groups = accumarray(inds, (1:size(A,1)).', [], @(x) {A(x,:)});
```

We thus get:

```
>> format compact
>> celldisp(groups)
groups{1} =
           0        2010           9          19
           0        2010           9          19
           0        2010           9          19
groups{2} =
           0        2010           9          20
groups{3} =
           0        2010          10          17
           0        2010          10          17
groups{4} =
           0        2010          10          18
           0        2010          10          18
groups{5} =
           0        2010          10          19
           0        2010          10          19
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `unique` to group each row by the month and day (columns 3 and 4) and then use [`splitapply`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html) to perform an operation on each group of rows that share a month/day. The operation that we're going to perform is to simply put them into a cell array: `@(x){x}`. The following code can accomplish this.

```
% Assign each unique month/day combination an ID
[~, ~, inds] = unique(A(:,[3 4]), 'rows');

% Divide up the rows based upon this ID
groups = splitapply(@(x){x}, A, inds);
```

And the result of `celldisp(groups)`

```
groups{1} =
           0        2010           9          19
           0        2010           9          19
           0        2010           9          19
groups{2} =
           0        2010           9          20
groups{3} =
           0        2010          10          17
           0        2010          10          17
groups{4} =
           0        2010          10          18
           0        2010          10          18
groups{5} =
           0        2010          10          19
           0        2010          10          19
```

That being said, it may be possible for you to do your analysis *without* actually splitting data into different pieces. This will likely be more performant as MATLAB is optimized for matrix operations.

More info on `splitapply` and grouping your data [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/grouping-variables-for-splitting-data.html)

Answer (score 3):

Here's another approach:

1. Sort rows of `A` based on the appropriate columns;
2. Detect chunk sizes based on a change in any value from those columns;
3. Split the sorted matrix based on those sizes.

Code:

```
key = [3 4]; % columns used as key for splitting
As = sortrows(A, [3 4]); % sort based on that (step 1)
chunks = diff([0; find(any(diff(As(:, [3 4]), [], 1), 2)); size(A,1)]); % sizes (step 2)
result = mat2cell(As, chunks, size(A,2)); % split with those sizes (step 3)
```

With your example data

```
A = [0 2010 10 19; 
     0 2010 10 19; 
     0 2010 10 18; 
     0 2010 10 18; 
     0 2010 10 17; 
     0 2010 10 17; 
     0 2010 9 20; 
     0 2010 9 19; 
     0 2010 9 19; 
     0 2010 9 19];
```

this gives

```
>> celldisp(result)
result{1} =
           0        2010           9          19
           0        2010           9          19
           0        2010           9          19
result{2} =
           0        2010           9          20
result{3} =
           0        2010          10          17
           0        2010          10          17
result{4} =
           0        2010          10          18
           0        2010          10          18
result{5} =
           0        2010          10          19
           0        2010          10          19
```